# XML / XSLT 1.0 - How to use XSL Template Match for a string of text?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a piece of code within an XSLT 1.0 document that I am having trouble getting to work.

How do I correctly get XSLT 1.0 to identify/match a string?

In the case below, `Description` holds the text string which in this example is `English (AAC) (2.0 ch)` however it will not always be this (or the same number of characters in the string).

Sometimes the string could be: `English (E-AC3) (2.0 ch)` for example

I have tried:

```
<xsl:template match="AudioTrack[ScannedTrack/TrackNumber > 0 and (ScannedTrack/Description = "English (AAC) (2.0 ch)")]">
```

but it is not working for me.

Can someone please help?

Comment: Your XPath is working for me just replaced the double quotes for the text value by single quotes: `AudioTrack[ScannedTrack/TrackNumber > 0 and (ScannedTrack/Description = 'English (AAC) (2.0 ch)')]`

Comment: I am an idiot. The one thing I didn't try. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be `'English (AAC) (2.0 ch)'` , thus:

```
<xsl:template match="AudioTrack[ScannedTrack/TrackNumber > 0 and (ScannedTrack/Description = 'English (AAC) (2.0 ch)')]">
```

using single quotation marks